# TTS does not talk with the headset connected

Tags: android, text-to-speech, headset

I am using this format for playback:

```
textToSpeech.speak("Text exemple", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. :).  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In this case, it would really help to know what you have tried already?  What have you verified NOT to be the problem?  As it is, someone could just tell you to turn the volume up.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the problem just by changing the headset. >.<